# Cross-thread operation not valid - StatusStrip controls

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a `StatusStrip` with one `ToolStripProgressBar` and one `ToolStripStatusLabel` in it. And I am facing the cross-thread operation problem when I need to update the values of them even if I do it in `progressChanged` event. So normally I need to handle it by `Invoke` method of the control after checking `InvokeRequired` attribute of the control. But in this case either `ToolStripProgressBar` or `ToolStripStatusLabel` does not have that attribute or that method. Below is the code snippet that throws the exception.

What is the correct way of invoking them?

```
void Uploader_ProgressChanged ( object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e )
{ 
    //ProgressBar is of type ToolStripProgressBar here throws exception
    CF.ProgressBar.Value += e.ProgressPercentage; 

    if ( e.UserState != null )
    { 
        // throws exception
        CF.ProgressStatusLabel.Text = "Uploading " + e.UserState; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid this problem you have to use a `MethodInvoker`

you can wrap your code this way:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    CF.ProgressBar.Value += e.ProgressPercentage; 

    if ( e.UserState != null )
    { 
        CF.ProgressStatusLabel.Text = "Uploading " + e.UserState; 
    }
}};
```

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.

Comment: Where should I exactly put this code? In my progress changed event `Invoke` is not event recognized as a keyword :/

Comment: Invoke is defined in `System.Windows.Forms.Control` - one of the base classes of `StatusStrip` but sadly not of `ToolStripProgressBar`. Can you place the handler in your `StatusStrip` and update your progress bar from there?

Comment: But I really wondered why `ToolStripProgressBar` control does not have that invoking capabilities.

Comment: because it is a `Component` subclass and no `Control` subclass